Overlay a Logo and Details on an Image After Capture
I am trying to achieve a result similar to the photo below. I want to display the file information, address, and logo in the top right corner of the image. I have developed an application that allows users to take a photo and add the file name, address, and a logo to it, but the result is not what I expected. The text takes up too much space on the captured photo.
If you have a solution to achieve a result similar to the desired photo, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks,
Nicolas
Output from my application


Expected result
I'm using opencv library on Android Studio to archieve the request I tried this code to
public static Bitmap addTextToImage(Bitmap bitmap, String filename, String address) {
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

    Scalar textColor = new Scalar(120,156,181); 

    int fontFace = Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double fontScale = 0.21; 
    int thickness = 1;
    int padding = 5; 
    
    String text = filename + " Adresse: " + address;

    Size textSize = Imgproc.getTextSize(text, fontFace, fontScale, thickness, new int[1]);

    // Position du texte : en bas à droite
    Point textPosition = new Point(
            mat.cols() - textSize.width - padding,
            mat.rows() - padding
    );

    // Dessiner un rectangle semi-transparent derrière le texte
    Rect textBackground = new Rect(
            (int) (textPosition.x - padding),
            (int) (textPosition.y - textSize.height - padding),
            (int) (textSize.width + padding * 2),
            (int) (textSize.height + padding)
    );

    Scalar backgroundColor = new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 150); 
    Imgproc.rectangle(mat, textBackground.tl(), textBackground.br(), backgroundColor, Imgproc.FILLED);
    
    Imgproc.putText(mat, text, textPosition, fontFace, fontScale, textColor, thickness);

    // Convertir à nouveau Mat en Bitmap
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, resultBitmap);

    return resultBitmap;
}

Picture code taken:
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Camera.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Location lastLoc = loc.getLastLoc();

        if(lastLoc == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        String filename = generateFileName();
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        Bitmap finalBitmap = PhotoAnnotator.addTextToImage(imageBitmap, filename, mSelectedAddress);

        saveImageToGallery(filename, finalBitmap, lastLoc);
    }
}


you can draw stuff without opencv. android can do that just fine. opencv is for computer vision, not for drawing. just saying... opencv is not the best choice for this.

@ChristophRackwitz I tried canvas/paint from android library but the result is bad too

... "bad" you say?

Yes, because the text is unreadable, and I want a font like the one in the first image. If you have any solutions to fix the issue, I'm open to suggestions. @ChristophRackwitz

I tried to update the code, but the text overlaying the bitmap does not look like the expected result, and the text becomes literally unreadable if it is too long. :
public class ImageTextOverlay {

public static Bitmap drawTextOnBitmap(Bitmap originalBitmap, String address, String fileName) {
    Bitmap bitmapWithText = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithText);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    int textSize = (int) (originalBitmap.getHeight() * 0.05);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize / 2);
    int margin = 20 - Math.round(paint.getTextSize());

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String text = fileName + " Adresse: " + address + " Date: " + date;

    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);

    // Positionner le texte en bas de l'image
    int xPos = margin;
    int yPos = originalBitmap.getHeight() - margin;

    canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);

    return bitmapWithText;
    }
}

